# Is there a way to customize the threshold for ViewPager scrolling?

Tags: android

I am not able to find a way to change the touch threshold for scrolling pages in ViewPager:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Looking at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.4_r1.2/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java), ViewPager has a method called determineTargetPage that checks to see if the move touch gesture distance > threshold range, but looks like there's no way to modify this range.

Any suggestions on how I can control this threshold (if at all possible)?

Comment: Have you tried extending `ViewPager` and overriding that method?

Comment: determineTargetPage is a private method

Comment: Then override the constructors, make your own custom `initViewPager` method, and have your custom constructors call that method instead. You can set the fling distance and velocity there.

Comment: I am not following. determineTargetPage is called by ViewPager's onTouchEvent, so how is overriding the constructor going to help?

Comment: It sets the fling distance and velocity, which are the factors of `determineTargetPage` that determine whether or not to switch pages.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, mFlingDistance and mMinimumVelocity/mMaximumVelocity are private fields, so you can't access them when you extend ViewPager.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Going out on a bit of a limb here; I have no doubt that you may have to tweak this concept and/or code.

I will recommend what I did in the comments above; to extend `ViewPager` and override its public constructors, and call a custom method which is a clone of `initViewPager()` (seen in the source you provided). However, as you noted, `mFlingDistance`, `mMinimumVelocity`, and `mMaximumVelocity` are `private` fields, so they can't be accessed by a subclass.

*(Note: You could also change these methods **after** the constructors are called, if you wanted to.)*

Here's where it gets a bit tricky. In Android, we can use the [Java Reflection API](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/java-reflection/) to make those fields accessible.

It should work something like this:

```
Class clss = getClass.getSuperClass();
Field flingField = clss.getDeclaredField("mFlingDistance"); // Of course create other variables for the other two fields
flingField.setAccessible(true);
flingField.setInt(this, <whatever int value you want>); // "this" must be the reference to the subclass object
```

Then, repeat this for the other two variables with whatever values you want. You may want to look at how these are calculated in the source.

Unfortunately, as much as I would like to recommend using Reflection to override the `private` method `determineTargetPage()`, I don't believe it's possible to do this--even with the expansive Reflection API.

Comment: Thanks Eric for explaining your approach. I can't use reflection and take dependence on an implementation detail (private member variables in this case) in production code - too risky.

Comment: Then I'm afraid it's not possible to do what you're looking to do. Unless you copied the entire source and modified it yourself...

Comment: Even though your approach is hackish, I am marking your answer as an accepted answer since there seems to be no clean way for controlling the distance and velocity parameters.