# Android ViewPager onPageSelected event

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager in my activity to show some images into it. Because of the `OutOfMemoryException` error I cannot add all the images into the ViewPager in onCreate method. So I have an Adapter which creates Layouts for each images.

```
viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                  

                LinearLayout LinLay=(LinearLayout) viewPager.findViewById(arg0);

                ImageView image=new ImageView(getBaseContext());
                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(LinLay.getTag().toString());
                image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                int padding = 0;

                image.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);


                LinLay.addView(image);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

I added this code to add images when user swipes the ViewPager right or left. But there is a bug. I want `onPageSelected` fires swipe event finished. It fires when swipe event starts.

How can I do it?

Comment: Try your code onPageScrolled or onPageScrollStateChanged

Answer (score 0):

Normally a page is swiped when it is 40% drawn. You could override that 40% with something like 80%, so the swipe-event triggers later.

here is another post about how to do that --> [Is there a way to customize the threshold for ViewPager scrolling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11731878/is-there-a-way-to-customize-the-threshold-for-viewpager-scrolling)